# What are the differences between active bandpass filter topologies?

Tags: active-filter, band-pass

I want to use a narrow band active bandpass filter but I found generally 2 topologies as seen below. What are the differences between them?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

The first one is an active narrow band pass filter
The lower one is a Multiple feedback topology

You can read details about them here 
[here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_7.html)
and
[here](https://www.changpuak.ch/electronics/downloads/sloa088.pdf) page 16-31

[here](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-218.pdf) is a design application for the Multiple feedback filter

Comment: Thanks for replying. what are the technical differences between them? I mean which one is better to use?

Comment: The differences are exactly what Andy wrote. Which one to use ? Well that depends entirely on the application.

Answer (score 2):

The first filter works but has limited capabilities in that the Q factor of the circuit is unalterable and quite a moderate/low value hence you don't get much out-of-band rejection. It is equivalent to a single order high pass followed by a single order low pass with a fixed Q of 0.5 (fairly low).

The 2nd filter is capable of delivering higher values of Q and this depends on the ratios of resistors and capacitors used. Given that it can deliver higher Q values, a much peakier (or narrow) band-pass filter can be made with superior band rejection. It is called a [multiple feedback band-pass filter](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/OPtazyuBakeisan.htm).

If you open the link and put values in for R1 and R2 at 1000 ohms and vary R3 up to some arbitrarily high value you will see that Q can be raised quite high.

Comment: Any explanation for the downvote?

Comment: I'm curios as well .. It's a good answer